# Self-taught: trying to center a textbox in the middle of the page by creating a div and using flex. It's currently centered at the top of the page

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
.align {
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="align">
  <p> This is filler text for a pretend blog </p>
</div>
```

Do I just add a bunch of padding to the top of the body? It does the trick but feels clunky and doesn't explain why flex isn't working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flexbox: center horizontally and vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026884/flexbox-center-horizontally-and-vertically)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the height of the page and use `justify-content: center;` and `align-items: center;`

```css
body {
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="align">
  <p> This is filler text for a pretend blog </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This was helpful to center the text but I'm trying to center the box that the text is within as well if that makes sense.

Comment: If you need to center the box then just apply the same styles to the parent element of the box. I have updated my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

The `p` element is at the vertical center of the `.align` element. This is not equal to being at the vertical center of the page. To make the `p` element be at the vertical center of the page, the `.align` element has to take up the whole height of the page. This could be done by applying `height: 100vh` to the `.align` element.

(If you want to horizontally center the `p` element, you have to apply `justify-content: center` to the `.align` element.)

(If the `.align` element is just for alignment, it could make sense to just remove it and simply apply

```css
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
```

to the `body`:)

```css
body {
    background: white;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<p>This is filler text for a pretend blog </p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm trying to center both the p element and the div element. It should look like a text box in the center of the page.

Answer (score 0):

CSS Grid makes the process pretty painless.

```css
/* remove default margin provided by browser user agent */
html {
  margin: 0;
}

/* remove default top margin for exact vertical centering */
.align p {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.align {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="align">
  <p> This is filler text for a pretend blog </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.align {
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 60%;
  height: 50vh;
  border: solid green 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="align">
  <p> This is filler text for a pretend blog </p>
</div>
```